# Material-UI V5: stylis-plugin-rtl works but the css value automatically gets the opposite value

Tags: material-ui, right-to-left

After adding the plugin to my code everything works well, but I've noticed that when I'm setting **horizontal** attribute's values (ex. direction, padding-left/right, right / left, etc.) - the actual value that applies is the **opposite** value.

For example, setting right: 10px will transform to right: 10px in the browser.

In my code:
[code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CUP4.png)

In dev tools:
[dev tools image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iif2D.png)

My question is:

Is it supposed to be like that because of the plugin, or is it an inner bug in the plugin / MUI system & theme provider?

Comment: Can you create a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) or share your full code?

Comment: @hotcakedev Sadly I can't since this is a customer's application :(